# How do you configure Azure Function authentication by code?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to configure the authentication for my Azure function via code, be it powershell, ARM template or an API? is this possible?

i'm under the impression that an Azure Function is nothing more then an App Service so i would assume it resolve around there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/?view=azps-2.0.0#app_service - there doesn't seem to be anything in the powershell.

https://resources.azure.com/ doesn't seem to give much information.

[image: configure Azure function authentication]

Comment: Did you find any solution? All the answers seem to answer a different question / way to authenticate. How can you change the authentication settings (add identity provider) through powershell, MS graph or arm templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some documentation on how to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity

You could create an PowerShell function app with MSI (Managed Service Identity) enable in a consumption plan. Here is some documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-functions-managed-identity/) on how to do that.

Once the function app is created, you can grant it access to a given resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-2.0.0#examples

Lastly, the PowerShell function app comes with a `profile.ps1` which contains code to authenticate against Azure via MSI out the box.

```
# Authenticate with Azure PowerShell using MSI.
# Remove this if you are not planning on using MSI or Azure PowerShell.
if ($env:MSI_SECRET -and (Get-Module -ListAvailable Az.Accounts)) {
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

Please give it a try and let us know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions Authentication are still pending. Currently AFAIK there is not a way to add authentication via code except with the `Function Host Keys`

You can track the issue here in [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33)

Answer (score 0):

Using terraform is a really good way of configuring these, a good example is below. Also az CLI 'az webapp auth' seems to have really good support now. PowerShell still seems to be lagging behind.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app